# How do I make a floating header?

Tags: html, css

Example :

Mjnichols.net

When you scroll down a white header appears, and then disappears when you scroll back up .how can I do this?

Comment: In case you're wondering why people are voting down your question, it's because you've asked a very broad question where you expect people to basically do the work for you, where this site is more about very specific programming questions that you've already thoroughly researched, and still can't find an answer.   This is something you could have easily googled, and followed a tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

   if (scroll >= 50) {
       $(".clearHeader").addClass("fix-navbar");
   } else {
       $(".clearHeader").removeClass("fix-navbar");
   }
});
```

Then style your header based on the `fix-navbar` class. Use `position: fixed;` to make it "sticky". the fix-navbar class will be present if scrolled past a certain point (change the 50 to change this point).

You will also require jQuery for the above code to work.

Comment: I think you mean use `position:fixed;` rather than static

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the best way to do this would be with jQuery, CSS3 transitions can also be used to make a smooth effect. The effect can be modified to work best for hour conditions.

```js
//Detect if document has scrolled
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    var scrollAmount = 100;
    //Check if user has scrolled enough
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > scrollAmount) {
        //Add white class
        $("#header").addClass('header_white');
    } else if ($("#header").hasClass('header_white')) {
        //Remove white class
        $("#header").removeClass('header_white');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color:red;
}
#header {
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
}

.header_white {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
    Blah Blah
</div>
Page contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage contentPage content
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need JavaScript for this to be able to detect when the user scrolls down. jQuery is overkill if you just need this functionality but just to help you get the idea, see this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sajadtorkamani/qaj6L1pk/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

if ($(this).scrollTop()>50)
 {
    $('#header').fadeIn();
 }
else
 {
  $('#header').fadeOut();
 }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
   .fix-navbar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
   }
```

I think that's the beginning of what you need. Hope it helps